# Django CSRF Error Cookie Not Set

Tags: django, csrf

I've looked through several Stack posts similar to this however none of the solutions I've tried have solved my issue.

View

```
def priceWatch(request, id):

    user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
    event = Event.objects.get(id = id)
    amount = request.POST['amount']
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        price_watch = PriceWatch(user = user, tic = event, price_watch = amount)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('eng:index', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('eng/price_watch_confirm.html', {'event' : event, 'amount' : amount}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
<form action="{% url 'eng:priceWatch' event.id %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

Set a Price Tracker for this Event: <input type="text" name="amount">

<input type="submit" value="Track">

</form>
```

The view loads a static page that simply confirms that the pricewatch object was created. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: I have been using CSRF successfully throughout my project up until this point, this is the only area where it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: do you have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings file?

Comment: Yes, I have. And I tried reordering the middleware classes so that CSRFViewMiddleware was after SessionMiddleware.

Comment: Did you add the context processor as well? `django.core.context_processors.csrf`

Comment: Especially, do you see the <input type="hidden" /> generated by th {% csrf_token %} in your HTML page ? If not, it's probably because you don't have activate the tag (cf the response of @limelights :) )

Comment: I did not have the context processor however upon adding it nothing has changed. The hidden key is in the HTML of the page and I have the tokens working properly in other parts of my project. Its just this one spot where I keep getting the 403 error.